# split a string on a character when it's in the middle of the string

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, split

I want to split a string on a character when it's in the middle of the string

Example :

```
string_1 = '-1232-1412'
string_2 = '1234-1243'
```

I want to have this :

```
output_string_1 = ['-1232','1412']
output_string_2 = ['1234','1243']
```

I tried this :

```
import re
In[1]: re.split(r'\w-',string_1)
Out[1]: ['-123', '1412']
```

but it deleted the last character before '-'

Comment: Do you mean like this? `(?!^)-(?!$)` https://regex101.com/r/Ppp5Qg/1

Answer (score 2):

One way could be to split the string asserting not the start of the string `^` and after matching `-` asserting not the end of the string `$` using a negative lookahead `(?!`

```
(?!^)-(?!$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ppp5Qg/1/) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/9bS9gU)

Answer (score 2):

You may use this regex with **word boundaries**:

```
\b-\b
```

This regex matches hyphen wrapper with word boundaries on either side thus only matching hyphen in the middle of word characters.

**Code:**

```
>>> reg = r'\b-\b'
>>> print (re.split(reg, '-1232-1412'))
['-1232', '1412']
>>> print (re.split(reg, '1234-1243'))
['1234', '1243']
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/W8e0n9/1)